# Android integer-xml value to string

Tags: java, android, xml

In my code I have an integer xml file and I want to use the values inside in my code.

But when I show them in my textview instead of 0 I get 2131361797.

Here is my xml:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="zero">0</integer>
    <integer name="minimum_number">0</integer>
    <integer name="maximum_number">12</integer>
</resources>
```

And here is my code:

```
correctValue.setText(R.integer.zero + "");
incorrectValue.setText(R.integer.maximum_number + "");
```

I have also tried `String.valueOf(R.integer.zero);`, but that also gave the same results.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `getResources().getInteger` method to get `int` value from `integers.xml` :

```
correctValue.setText(String.valueOf(
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.zero)));
```